# Cannot get rid of White outline in three js canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

im recently trying to modify a script from codepen but im having some troubles. I have to insert all the code in just one HTML file but when i do so a white outline/border appears around my canvas.

here's the website i'm uploading the code where the issue is displayed https://alsndr.altervista.org/midnightmadness/

here's the style

```
    overflow:hidden;
        width:100%;
        border:0!important;
  }
.vsc-initialized{
  border: none!important;
  padding:none!important;
}
  canvas {
    display: block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
    align: center;
    outline:none;
    overflow:hidden;
  }

  .world {
    position: absolute;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    background: #FF4066;
  }
```

here's the js where i declare the canvas size

```
this.renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    this.renderer.setSize(width, height);
    this.container = document.getElementsByClassName("world")[0];
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.aspectRatio = width / height;
```

here are the resize functions:

```
updateSize(w, h) {
    this.renderer.setSize(w, h);
    this.camera.aspect = w / h;
    this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }

function domIsReady() {
  world = new World(this.container, this.renderer, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  window.addEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize, false);
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove, false);
  handleWindowResize();
  world.loop();
}



function handleWindowResize() {
  world.updateSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Below CSS.

```
body{ margin: 0; }
```